# Getting error while printing xls report for odoo 10

Tags: report, odoo, odoo-10, xls

I am using Odoo10 and I'm getting following error while print xls report  " Sheetname 'A8', with case ignored, is already in use.: (, Exception(u"Sheetname 'A8', with case ignored, is already in use.",), ) ". So, how to solve this problem?

My code is below:

**Python:**

```py
from odoo.addons.report_xlsx.report.report_xlsx import ReportXlsx
class PartnerXlsx(ReportXlsx):
    def generate_xlsx_report(self, workbook, data, partners):
        for obj in partners:
            report_name = obj.name
            # One sheet by partner
            sheet = workbook.add_worksheet(report_name[:31])
            bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
            sheet.write(0, 0, obj.name, bold)
PartnerXlsx('report.res.partner.xlsx', 
            'res.partner')
```

**Xml:**

```xml
<odoo>
    <data>
        <report id="partner_xlsx"
                model="res.partner"
                string="Print to XLSX"
                report_type="xlsx"
                name="res.partner.xlsx"
                file="res.partner.xlsx"
                attachment_use="False"/>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you don't have the name `A8` more than once in partner table.
If the same name exists more than once try either below methods.

1. Use sheet name as a combination of partner name and code.
2. Use python `try and exception` method. If an exception occurs, then change the name.

For your reference:

1. [DuplicateWorksheetName](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/exceptions.html#DuplicateWorksheetName)
2. [Python Exceptions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_exceptions.htm)

Comment: But i have many customers with same name. So, how to remove this validation.

Comment: Updated my answer.